# Is there a way using ffprobe (fluent-ffmpeg) input with a read stream in node.js?

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg

I am using fluent-ffmpeg in my code, my main goal is to get the audio/video duration,
I need to use stream as my input.

According the document,
https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg#reading-video-metadata

```
ffmpeg('/path/to/file1.avi')
  .input('/path/to/file2.avi')
  .ffprobe(function(err, data) {
    console.log('file2 metadata:');
    console.dir(data);
  });

ffmpeg('/path/to/file1.avi')
  .input('/path/to/file2.avi')
  .ffprobe(0, function(err, data) {
    console.log('file1 metadata:');
    console.dir(data);
  });
```

I have tried these

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg')
const fs = require('fs')

filepath = './scratch_file/assets_audios_10000.wav'
stream = fs.createReadStream(filepath)
ffmpeg(stream)
.input(filepath) // have to put a file path here, possible path dependent
.ffprobe(function (err, metadata) {
    if (err){throw err}
    console.log(metadata.format.duration);
}) //success printing the duration
```

Above successfully returned the duration

```
ffmpeg(stream)
.input(stream) //
.ffprobe(function (err, metadata) {
    if (err){throw err}
    console.log(metadata.format.duration);
}) // failed
```

Above failed.

```
ffmpeg(stream)
.ffprobe(function (err, metadata) {
    if (err){throw err}
    console.log(metadata.format.duration);
}) //returned "N/A"
```

Returned N/A

Can nyone help? I would need something like

`ffmpeg.ffprobe(stream, (metadata) => {console.log(metadata.format.duration)} )`

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The following code worked for me.

```
  let ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg')

  // create a new readable stream from whatever buffer you have
  let readStream = new Readable()
  readStream._read = () => {}
  readStream.push(imageBufferObject.buffer)
  readStream.push(null)

 // I used a call to a promise based function to await the response
 let metadata = await get_video_meta_data(readStream)
 console.log(metadata)

 async function get_video_meta_data(stream){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    ffmpeg.ffprobe(stream, (err, meta)=>{
      resolve(meta)
    })
 })
}
```

Simply feeding in the readable stream into `ffmpeg.ffprobe()` where it expects the file path seems to have worked for me, as I can extract the meta data without writing to disk.